# AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, mongoengine

I want to add documentation for the Django app

1. I use rest_framework_mongoengine, rest_framework
2. OpenAPI 3.0, drf-spectacular swagger

**model :**

```
from mongoengine import *

class Service(Document):
    student_id = StringField(required=True)
    name = StringField(max_length=50)
    age = IntField()
```

**serializer:**

```
from Service.models import Service
from rest_framework_mongoengine import serializers as mongoserializers

class ServiceSerializer(mongoserializers.DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views:**

```
import mongoengine
from .models import Service
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import ServiceSerializer
from .docs import list_service, create_service, update_service, delete_service
from rest_framework_mongoengine.viewsets import ModelViewSet as MongoModelViewSet


mongoengine.connect(db='Ecommerce', host='localhost:27017')

@create_service()
class CreateServiceAPI(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Service.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
```

I created  documentation but when I execute any endpoint in documentation this error happens

> "AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'model'"

[image]

anyone can help me to solve this problem

Comment: HI! Welcome to SO. Please do not upload pictures of your code. Put your code directly in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change model to add fields:**

```js
from django_mongoengine import Document, fields

class Service(Document):
    student_id = fields.StringField(blank=True)
    name = fields.StringField(max_length=50)
    age = fields.IntField()
```